# How to add a slide bar in a table?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been creating an app where there are Clients that I can add to a table, the problem is, I need a scrollbar to scroll through all the clients since the app Height is limited and the clients aren't.
Using tkinter I found a way to create a "table" using Entry and grid, but what if I want to create 100 rows? they would be outside of the view, so that's why the need of a scrollbar.

For those of you who know Java, I wanted to create something similar to Jtable, it has a method to create row, delete row, and it generates automatically that scrollbar as soon as the JTable runs out of space.

I've tried to use TkTable from ttk and mess around with some properties, but I preferred how Entries look.

```py
root = Tk()

root.geometry("1200x900")

for i in range(10):
    e = Entry(relief=RIDGE)
    e.grid(row=i, column=2, sticky=N)

root.mainloop()
```

I created a root = Tk() and used root to grid them.
You'll see 10 Entries on top of the other.

Comment: Tkinter has `Scrollbar` but it works only with `Text`, `Listbox` or `Canvas`. On internet you can find examples of `ScrolledFarme` which uses `Scrollbar` to scroll `Frame` on `Canvas` and you can put `Entries` in this `Frame` to scroll them. OR see [Treeview](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a window contains many widgets, they might not all be visible. However, neither a window (Tk or Toplevel instance) nor a Entry are scrollable.

**One solution to make the window content scrollable is to put all the widgets in a Frame, and then, embed this Frame in a Canvas using the create_window method.**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
scroll_y = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

frame = Frame(canvas)

# group of widgets
for i in range(100):
    e = Entry(frame, relief=RIDGE, width = 100)
    e.grid(row=i, column=2, sticky=N)

# put the frame in the canvas
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=frame)
# make sure everything is displayed before configuring the scrollregion
canvas.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'),
                 yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
scroll_y.pack(fill='y', side='right')

root.mainloop()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! that was what I was really looking for.